# On-click Textarea box in Angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to angular.js I want to know how to add the text area when onclick the image.

```
.......
.....
.....
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="stu in Studentlist">
<td>{{stu.rollno}}</td>
<td>{{stu.name}}</td>
<td><img src="assets/img/reason.png"></td>
</tr>
.....
.....
```

My question is when I am click the reason.png,need to display the text area in    below table.How to achive this in Angular js.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply ng-click on your image as below

```
<td><img src="assets/img/reason.png" ng-click="showTextArea=true"></td>
```

And you can define your text area where you can use ng-show to show is when showTextArea is true.

```
i.e <textarea ng-show="showTextArea"></textarea>
```

Comment: Many Thanks ! i need to one more doubt.No need to anything add for text area showing in controller ?

Comment: In controller, you can write $scope.showTextArea = false

Comment: or even in within you html it self you can initialize it using ng-init="showTextArea = false"